# For loop with special condition

Tags: java, for-loop, syntax

```
public int minCompletionTime() { // finds minCompletionTime
  int time = -1;

  for(Job j : jobs) { 
    if (j.getStartTime() == -1) {
      return -1;
    }
  }

  for (Job j : jobs) { //Calculate the minimum completion time
     if (j.getStartTime() + j.time > time) {
         time = j.getStartTime() + j.time;
     }
  }

  return time;
}
```

Can someone explain the loop condition? it looks new to for me. Thank you

Comment: They enumerate a collection (jobs)

Comment: There is no explicit loop condition, it is just an iteration on each jobs.

Comment: Also read _enhanced for_ in [The Java™ Tutorials: The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: thank you, I dont know that they call it is foreach. Make sense now

Answer (score 1):

This is an enhanced for statement. The short version - `jobs` is a collection or an array of `Job` objects, and the loop iterates over it and assigns a new `Job j` in each iteration. You could think of it as syntactic sugar equivalent to something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jobs.size(); ++i) {
    Job j = jobs.get(i);
    // Rest of the loop...
```

You can read more about this syntax in [Oracle's tutorial about the `for` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 1):

These loops are so-called 'for-each' loops. And their name reflects exactly what they are doing. They execute the task defined in the body for every element in the Collection/array. Let's take a look at a more simple example:

```
int[] test = new int[] { 5, 7, 9, 3, 4, 9 };
for(int i : test) 
{
  System.out.print( i + " " );
}
```

The output of this would be :

`5 7 9 3 4 9`